# Selection gets removed in master view after calling reloadData on detail view

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a Split View Controller as a root controller, both (master, detail) are extended with `UITableViewController`. So whenever I make a selection on master view cell, detail view shows up and then the `cell.selectionStyle` on master view cell gets removed (apparently).

It happens after table view data is loaded (viewDidLoad) or reloaded.

Anyone gone through this type of problem or have any knowledge/workaround ??? How can detail view controller affect master in this sense..

**EDIT**

I have a popover menu also ext with `UITableViewController`, master view cell shows the same behavior when it pops up. But another detail view controller is extended with `Collectionviewcontroller`, when this one shows up, master view i.e. table view cell... does not show abnormality

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"EventRowCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:[EventRowCell identifier]];

    [self loadCalendarResultController]; // NSFetchedResultsController stuff...
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[self.resultController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.resultController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 125.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EventRowCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[EventRowCell identifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[EventRowCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:[EventRowCell identifier]];
}
    cell.textLabel.text = @"text";
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.resultController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

    if (!formatter)
    {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
        NSString *formatTemplate = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dd MMMM eeee" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [formatter setDateFormat:formatTemplate];
    }
    return [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[sectionInfo name] doubleValue]]];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *) loadresultController {
    if (_resultController != nil) {
        return _resultController;
    }
    _resultController = [[DataManager instance] getCalendarResults:self.module withDelegate:self];
    return _resultController;
}
```

MasterViewController
Using NSFetchRequest to fetch data, customized cell.

DetailViewController
Using NSFetchedResultsController to fetch the data, customized cell.